# Does "snatch up" have the meaning "rush to purchase"?

Tags: meaning

One of the famous English teachers in Taiwan tells the reader that "snatch ... up" has the meaning "rush to purchase". I looked *snatch* up in a lot of dictionaries and can't find that meaning. Could anyone that are native speakers corroborate it? Thanks.

Comment: It's an [idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/snatch+up).

Comment: Yes, "snatch up" is an idiom meaning "rush to purchase" (as with an item that is priced well below normal price).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say the usage is more than a little "malapropistic".

> ***Snap*** up a bargain [(139 hits in Google Books)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22shoppers%20snapped%20up%20bargains%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22snap%20up%20a%20bargain%22)
>    ***Snatch*** up a bargain [(5 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22shoppers%20snapped%20up%20bargains%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22snatch%20up%20a%20bargain%22)

---

The standard "phrasal verb" verb usage even gets its own definition in [thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/snap+up)...

> **snap up** *Fig. to purchase something quickly, because the price is low or because the item is so hard to find.*

...but I'd be very surprised<sup>1</sup> if any dictionaries defined that specific figurative sense for *snatch up*.

<sup>1</sup> [I **was indeed** surprised](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267641/does-snatch-up-have-the-meaning-rush-to-purchase/267645?noredirect=1#comment589667_267641) (all credit to @jxh). But given the usage disparity indicated above (and that in spite of the fact that *in other contexts,* the collocation ***snatch[ed] up*** is far more common than ***snap[ped] up***, I stand by the broad thrust of my position here.

Comment: Your explanation is reasonable. Thanks for pointing out "snap up" which I didn't know.

Comment: The teacher got it wrong. *Snatch up* idiom has to do with acquiring as many as possible, and less with acquiring it quickly (although arguably correlated).

Comment: @jxh: I'm not sure I'd go so far as to say the teacher got it *wrong*. By which I mean it's perfectly *possible* to use "snatch up" in such contexts, so if the teacher was simply explaining what those words meant *in some specific example usage*, it would be a reasonable thing to say. But as of right now I'm in two minds as to whether to *downvote* Nickknack's answer, which implies that even *with no specific context* it's reasonable to assume that as a possible meaning. (Though if no-one finds a dictionary to refute what I said above, I probably *will* downvote it! :)

Comment: See link in my comment under the question.

Comment: @jxh: I guess that saves Nickknack from a downvote! I still think that at almost 30:1, the usage preference figures I've cited suggest it's a bit silly to *teach* the less common usage without ensuring that students are aware of the *more* common one. But I was never willing to say it's actually wrong - provided you observe basic grammar and can make yourself understood, anything goes. But if ***I*** were learning a foreign language, I'd rather get the most common forms under my belt first, so I wouldn't be too happy working under a teacher who neglected/didn't know to do that.

Comment: I would probably have used "snatch up" and would consider "snap up" a hair "odd" in comparison.  And certainly it is splitting hairs to insist that "snatch up" only applies to purchasing multiple items.

Comment: Snatch up leads snap up in a Google ngram comparing the two by a very small margin now, always running neck and neck since about 1950. Before that, snatch up led by a wider margin.  But snatch up's lead has been quite consistent, with only a brief time in the 1980s when they actually crossed. So I don't see how anyone can dismiss this usage.  Maybe it's regional.  Here in the NE US, I'd more likely say snatch than snap in this usage, but I'd have no trouble understanding snap. Note that snatch can have a sexual connotation, so maybe that's why snap is used, despite being less logical a choice.

Comment: Ngram shows *snatched up* dominates *snapped up*.

Comment: @jxh: I assume by that you mean [***snatched up** is more common than **snapped up***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=snatched+up%2Csnapped+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csnatched%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnapped%20up%3B%2Cc0). But that's a pretty meaningless observation, given that only a tiny fraction of all instances of ***snapped up*** (and something like a *thirtieth* of that fraction for ***snatched up***) will apply to the usage under consideration. Check my link and you can easily prove that for yourself.

Comment: ...in fact, noting that "contextless" ***snatched up*** is maybe twice as common as ***snapped up***, it would be quite reasonable to suppose that for any *specific* occurrence of either form, the latter is *sixty* times more likely to apply to the sense we're dealing with here. There's no point in flogging a dead horse.

Comment: I don't really know how to interpret those findings. Compare *snatched something up* to *snapped something up*. The idiom usage is different.

Comment: @jxh: I don't see any *syntactic* difference - they're both "phrasal verbs" which allow the object to be interpolated, so *He snatched his head up* and *She snapped the cheap tickets up* are just as valid as the versions where the verb and preposition are kept together. But assuming you're a native speaker, I can't really understand how you could apparently be unaware/skeptical of the *huge* difference in idiomatic preference in the current context.

Comment: I am not disagreeing with your observations. My personal experience is different. In recent times, I more often hear *snag* than either *snap* or *snatch*.

Comment: @jxh: Yeah - I often hear/use *snag* (or *snaffle*) myself in this context. But you seem to be suggesting that *from your perspective*, the specific form ***snatch up a bargain*** seems "more common" than ***snap up***. I can understand the possibility that you personally might favour the less common form, but I simply can't see how you'd be unaware that it is in fact less common among the general population of Anglophones. It hardly seems like something that would be subject to significant "regional variation" among native speakers.

Comment: I guess I am just colored from being raised in a small isolated town in the US midwest. Another thing to note, the book search link shows *snap one up* versus *snatch one up* at a 2:1 (not 500:1 like I originally thought, quotes around the phrase are important!) ratio. But Ngram shows their usage wavering back and forth. Anyway, you already got my +1! Fun chat.